# Eclipse CDT+RSE+PTP: how to set up a synchronized remote project with remote indexing?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-rse

This C project I am supposed to work on is taking too long(>5 hours) to do indexing on local, also the building depends on the environment setting on a remote server.

So I am thinking to have the server doing the indexing and at the same time keep a local copy of the project just for the fast editing and browsing. After some search on google, I found that Eclipse PTP5.0 's synchronized remote project is very close to what I want.

But the docs doesn't seem very clear how to set it up. I have tried many times, no success.

I see many places with Remote Tools and RSE as options, which one do I choose? How are they different? Do I have to run rdt-server manually (I don't have the root access on the server)? Is it possible to do this only with ssh without opening another port on the server?

Is there a guide for this kind of setup?
Or, any other ways to achieve this?

Thanks !

**EDIT:**
on a second thought, synchronise doesn't seem very important to me since PTP is doing it through git anyway. So remote indexing is what I need the most.

Answer (score 0):

Remote Indexing won't speed up indexing. The indexer isn't parallel (yet), so using a larger server won't help.

For help on how to setup a synchronized project see: 
http://wiki.eclipse.org/PTP/sync-projects
Feel free to ask questions at ptp-user@eclipse.org.